# R ggplot - Boxplot with fill displaying different values than bargraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I have a boxplot generated using the following code, and after checking the dataset all the values are correct here.

```
myplot <- inDATA %>% filter(PARAMCD=="param1") %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x=ACTARMCD,y=AVAL,fill=ACTARMCD))+
            geom_boxplot()+
            stat_summary(fun.y=mean,na.rm=TRUE,shape=25,col='black',geom='point')
```

[image: Boxplot 1 Link]

I want to generate a second boxplot where I split the x variable into different groups by applying a different variable as a fill. I use the following code, but the values present in the graph are incorrect.

```
myplot <- inDATA %>% filter(PARAMCD=="param1") %>% 
            group_by(ACTARMCD, RESPFL) %>%  
            ggplot(aes(x=ACTARMCD,y=AVAL))+
            geom_boxplot(aes(fill=RESPFL))
```

[image: Boxplot 2 Link]

However when I generate a bargraph using this code, the numbers are correct.

```
myplot <- inDATA %>%  
            filter(PARAMCD=="param1") %>% 
            group_by(ACTARMCD,RESPFL) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(AVAL = mean(AVAL, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x=ACTARMCD,y=AVAL,fill=RESPFL))+
            geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image: Bargraph Link]

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly with the second boxplot?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using randomly generated data resembling your data. Could you share your `inDATA` via `dput()`? What I used to replicate which works as expected is: `inDATA <- data.frame(AVAL = rnorm(500,11000,5000), ACTARMCD = sample(c("GROUP_A","GROUP_B"), 500, replace = T), PARAMCD = "param1", RESPFL = sample(c("N","Y"), 500, replace = T))`

Comment: @juljo, I unfortunately can't upload any data because it's proprietary company data. However, I ended up switching from ggplot to plotly using the code below and this now works as anticipated. Does anybody know why ggplot wouldn't work here?```myplot <- inDATA %>% filter(PARAMCD=="param1") %>% 
          plot_ly(x = ~ACTARMCD, y = ~AVAL, color = ~RESPFL, type = "box",boxmean=TRUE) %>% 
          layout(boxmode = "group")```

Comment: I doubt anyone can give a definitive explanation without being able to reproduce the problem, but for what it's worth, the `group_by(x_variable, fill_variable)` line isn't necessary for your boxplot code in ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by using plotly instead of ggplot. The code that worked is:

```
myplot <- inDATA %>% filter(PARAMCD=="param1") %>% 
plot_ly(x = ~ACTARMCD, y = ~AVAL, color = ~RESPFL, type = "box",boxmean=TRUE) %>% layout(boxmode = "group")
```